# what is the difference between (params[:id]) and params([:post_id ]) in rails both represent to the same controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end

def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with routing.  If you only route for a controller, for instance, /comments/:id then you only need to use params[:id] to get the params, but if you have multiple controllers and multiple id's involved and accessible then it would be something like /posts/:id/comments/:comment_id to avoid confusion between which :id you accessing.

```
def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

The above code would be very problematic because rails doesn't know which :id to grab so we differentiate using :post_id and :comment_id

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing we see a part of a CommentsController here. And I assume that each Comment belongs to a Post. So the `id` here will reference a Comment (model) and the `post_id` references a Post. You should have a closer look into the Comment and Post models.